# The result of FCM clustering for my Testset in matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, fuzzy

I used fcm function in matlab with my dataset which is trainset.
now I have some testset.

[center,U,obj_fcn] = fcm(train ,cluster_number);

after clustering trainset , how can I ask the degree of membership and most probable cluster for my testset? does it have function ?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Probably the distance between new data and centers which has been determinated . do U have another idea?

Comment: See the FCM paper for how points are assigned to clusters. It's fuzzy, a point can belong to more than one cluster.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse for example if membership degree for a cluster is 0.68 it is the most probable and it mostly belongs to this cluster. but in fuzzy clustering , a data belongs to all cluster but weak and strong( depend on membership degree)

Comment: @Anony-Mousse yes ,  you 're right . but how to determine these degrees for a new data test?

Comment: Exactly as you do for the old data set...